# Table rename in toad

Tags: toad

I have renamed a table I toad.
After renaming the table just disappered.
I have right clicked on the table and clicked on rename option.
It asked me to edit the name.
I have edited and clicked ok.
It displayed a message that ' table or view does not exist' and then the whole table and data is lost.
Can we restore the previous table?
Please suggest some ways.
Thank u.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the view to see if the table with its new name might appear?  This sounds like it might just be a UI quirk.

Comment: Yes..after refreshing the previous table is also gone

Comment: What version of Toad? Can you reproduce with a new table that you create just for testing? It would be a coincidence, but is it possible that the table was dropped elsewhere while you were in the midst of renaming? You'll need to restore the table and its data from your backups. There is no way in Toad to do so automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you have applied a filter in your table view list, you need to clear it.

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: User with less reputation can't do comments.